# Getting POST values from a Django request when they start with the same string

Tags: python, django

I have a form on my site that allows the user to add names to an object. The user can hit a plus button to add another name or a minus button to remove a name. I need to be able to easily pull all POST variables that start with a name.

For example. A user adds two names so we have two text boxes names 'name0' and 'name1'. Is there a way that I can pull those two values without know how many I may have?

One reason I want to do this without knowing is because they could do any number of add and remove functions on the list of names. So I could end up with this:

'name2', 'name10', 'name11'

for the names that come in. I don't want to have to know the exact values. I just want to pull all POST variables that start with 'name'.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use formset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate through all POST elements and just keep the ones starting with 'name':

```
names = [v for k, v in request.POST.items() if k.startswith('name')]
```

but that's really the wrong way to do it. You shouldn't be calling your fields different names at all: just have all the fields as `'name'`. HTTP happily posts all the data as different elements of the same variable, and you can get them back in Django via `request.POST.getlist('name')`.

Comment: Oh, I have separate fields for first name and last name. I need to be able to line the first name up with the last name. I should have mentioned this. So I need to match name0 with last_name0 and so forth.

Comment: Could you just not ask for their full name and then split it into first and last name later?

Comment: No, because some first names are things like Mary Ann. Which would make it hard to determine. Same thing could happen for a last name.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, like Daniel said, so I add the next

posted =    [{k.replace('person__',''):v} for k, v in request.POST.items() if k.startswith('person__')]

then I can use a model form with posted data